# What's the definition of weight in localization theorem?

Tags: symplectic-geometry, equivariant-cohomology, moment-map

I am currently reading a book on symplectic topology. I may have skipped some pages so find it confusing about the **Duistermaat-Heckman theorem**. In the book it states that

Assume Hamiltonian function $H:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a Morse function which generates a circle action, then
$$
\int_{M} e^{-\hbar H} \frac{\omega^{n}}{n !}=\sum_{p} \frac{e^{-\hbar H(p)}}{\hbar^{n} e(p)}
$$
for $\hbar \in \mathbb{C}$. The right sum runs over all critical points of $H$, $e(p) \in \mathbb{Z}$ is the product of **weights** at $p$.

I didn't find the definition of **weight** near few pages. I wonder anyone can give me a reference to understand this phrase. Any comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The formula you wrote assumes that the action has isolated fixed points, so that the right hand side is a finite sum. Let $p$ be a fixed point of the action, then the circle $S^{1}$ acts on $T_{p}(M)$ by taking the differential of the corresponding mappings. This gives $T_{p}(M)$ the structure of a $S^{1}$-representation. Minor technichal point: actually it is a complex reprentation since we can always pick an invariant almost complex structure compatible with the symplectic form (this is also proved in Mcduff-Salamon).

Anyway, the irreducible (complex) representations of $S^{1}$ are naturally identified with $\mathbb{Z}$, where the representation corresponding to $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is the reprenation $z.w = z^{n}w$ for $z \in S^{1}=U(1)$ and $ w \in \mathbb{C}$. This $n$ is called the weight of the representation. In general we split a $2n$-dimensional representation into irreducibles and the weights are just the $n$-tuple consisting of the weights of each summand. The weight at $p$ is just the weight of the representation on $T_{p}(M)$

Comment: Thanks for answering me this is really helpful!

Comment: Why is the representation of the circle group always the direct sum of representation on complex plane? I mean how does the splitting work out?

Comment: Irreducible representations of $S^{1}$ are classified, they are all 1-dimensional of the above form (almost any book on rep theory of lie groups will cover this), then you just split the representation into irreducibles, does that help?

Comment: Thanks. I just know few definitions in representation theory so sorry for the question but I get the idea. @Nick L